Picard Lindelof Theorem and Interval of Uniqueness
In the Picard Lindelof theorem, it states that the existence and uniqueness of a solution to the IVP is valid in a certain interval around the initial point $t_0$, denote this interval $$[t_0-\epsilon,t_0+\epsilon]$$ The theorem states not only the existence and uniqueness of the solution to the IVP, but the existence of this interval. I wanted to ask, in the proof of this theorem that utilizes the uniform convergence of the Picard iterations, where is this interval justified? I feel like the proof justifies the convergence of these estimations at $t_0$, but I don't understand where the existence of this interval is justified.

You can give an esteem of $\epsilon$ as $\epsilon<\min\left{a, \frac bM, \frac 1L \right}$ where $I\times J={|x-x_0|\le a, |y-y_0|\le b }$, L is the lipschitz constant of $f$ and $M=\max_{I\times J} |f(x,y)|$
